# Django Invalid block tag: 'urls' error on loading tag

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying a tutorial to load a ML script into Django.
I've completed the tutorial but right now i'm getting an error
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Invalid block tag on line 9: 'urls'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Titanic survival prediction</h1>
    <form action="{% urls 'result' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
   extra code with form items
    </form>
```

URLS file in python:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from djangoweek import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('result/', views.result, name='result'),
]
```

I've looked at other questions at stack but I don't got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tag with name `urls`. But, there is a template tag [`{% url 'name' %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url). So, simply do:

```
<form action="{% url 'result' %}">    <---- here
      {% csrf_token %}
   extra code with form items
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

write url instead of urls

```
{% url 'result' %}
```

instead of

```
{% urls 'result' %}
```